# Filter CSV from pg-promise takes only the first value from array

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

**My pg-promise query (2 ids in array passed in):**

```
db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($1:csv)`, team.member_ids)
```

**Console output of query and params passed to pg-promise:**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($1:csv) [ 1, 2 ]
//Fails one row returned, two expected
```

**However I get only one result. If I run the following query in psql I get two results:**

```
select * from users where user_id IN (1,2);
//Works successfully with two rows returned
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: when I run db.any(`SELECT user_id FROM users`) I get:
[ { user_id: 2 }, { user_id: 1 } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [Query Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#query-formatting), how one value versus array changes the values interpretation:

> This however works only for types `number`, `bigint`, `string`, `boolean`, `Date` and `null`, because types like `Array` and `Object` change the way parameters are interpreted.

```
db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($1:csv)`, team.member_ids)
//=> SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1)
```

Because above you are passing in the value-array itself directly, `$1` refers to the first element in that array. To make `$1` refer to the entire value-array, that value itself needs to be inside an array:

```
db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($1:csv)`, [team.member_ids])
//=> SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
```

Alternatively, the recommended use of [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) makes the code more concise:

```
db.any(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($<member_ids:csv>)`, team)
//=> SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
```

In general, use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) to see what queries are being executed.